# Python Need to build models for Linear regression and Decision Tree

Tags: python

I am trying to train the model

```
TreeReg = DecisionTreeRegressor()
TreeReg.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred_Train = TreeReg.predict(X_train) #predictions on Training set
y_pred_Test = TreeReg.predict(X_test) #predictions on testing set
```

It's giving me an error message: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3/1/2019'`

Answer (score 0):

Linear models need continuous values, (example 4 or 3.5)

You're passing a datetime/string value into it and model can't use this.

The model you used converts each line to a float value. Since that datetime thing can't converted to a float it raises an error.

If your all column Is like that value, a datetime column, then try this:

```
df['ThisCol'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ThisCol'])
df['Year'] = df['ThisCol'].dt.year
df['Month'] = df['ThisCol'].dt.month
```

You can use month and year values in your model.

you can check the docs for further information about datetime!